# Observing SMS send by one application in second application

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver, smsmanager

I am designing one application in which I want to observe the sms send by another application (not the default application which uses db or content provider) uses SMSmanager class like

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, "some text", null, null);
```

I am able to observe sms send by default application and google hangout with

```
ContentResolver contentresolver=this.getContentResolver();
contentresolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), true,yourObserver);
```

So finally I want to observe the SMS send by application which does not uses content provider.

Any help ???

Comment: Is there any system broadcast for sent SMS ??